# Sliding drawer in the same layout

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

Do you know how to achieve the same effect as winamp for android ? I want to do the similar thing. That is when I click on listview, sliding drawer popup. But so far I only can show the sliding drawer in new activity not in the same.

How can I achieve in overlap view. That is when I close the drawer, the layout is show at the front, and the sliding handle is on the layout, when I open the drawer, it covers the main layout.

Any ideas about that ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 11):

Step #1: Create a `RelativeLayout`

Step #2: Put the rest of your UI in the `RelativeLayout`

Step #3: Put the `SlidingDrawer` in the `RelativeLayout` as a later child then the rest of the UI (e.g., in layout XML, have it as the last child element of the `RelativeLayout`)

Children of `RelativeLayout` (and `FrameLayout`) stack on top of one another on the Z-axis (i.e., out the face of the screen). Hence, later children will overlap earlier ones. By putting your `SlidingDrawer` last, it will overlap everything else when opened.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **CommonsWare** you helped me,I do not have much reputation to vote up. Here is my sample layout...

I used `it.sephiroth.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer` as the SlidingDrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_open">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_open"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/open"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New EditText"
            android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"

        panel:direction="topToBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        panel:handle="@+id/handle"
        panel:content="@+id/content">
    <include
            android:id="@id/content"
            layout="@layout/pen_content" />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40px"
            android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
</it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```