# How to make android's sliding drawer visible in the foreground?

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I ran into a road block when I was adding the sliding drawer widget to my layout. I added it and everything works fine. The problem is that when I have a layout that is fills the height the sliding drawer's handle is no longer visible. Is there a way to make the handle visible by putting it in the foreground or maybe another way to achieve this?

The example that I am playing with is from:

https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/

All I edited from the above site is the .xml file below. Thank you ahead of time, I will be standing by....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blah Blah Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="38dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">

        <bear.exmaple.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </bear.exmaple.CustomView>


        <ImageView android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tray_handle_normal" />

    </SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to this question and it was as simple as adding all the Views/Layouts in a relative layout and making sure the sliding drawer is the final addition. Here is the link to where the answer lies:

[Sliding drawer in the same layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166197/sliding-drawer-in-the-same-layout)